# Create the page with hyperlinks from txt file

Tags: php

I would like to know if you can create a php page, by importing data from a txt file, let me explain better (I hope) I have a .txt file which is composed as follows:

```
Link 1
http://www.example.com/index1.php
Link 2
http://www.example.com/index2.php
Link 3
http://www.example.com/index3.php
```

is possible with a php script to create a page in php so

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index1.php">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/index2.php">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/index3.php">Link 3</a>
```

how can I do,thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get an (useful) answer. Also, please not that [so] is not a coding service; nobody will write the code for you. Post your attempts and describe the issues you encountered.

Comment: You can read the file with `php` file functions and then always read 2 lines. Then `echo` the second line to a `href`.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: with the answer, can you give me an example of how to set up the script?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
   $links = File("put path to file here");
   foreach ($links as $key=>$val)
      if ($key%2) $link_name = $val;
        else
           print "<a href='$val'>$link_name</a>";

?>
```

Comment: what is `File`?

Comment: the file and named as mylink.m3u

Comment: no, I asked @diavolic if php has such built in function `File` -))

Comment: I had not realized, the file and a simple txt file structured as in the example, alternating row with the name of the link and in line with the html address

Comment: +1: i've generally used `file_get_contents` or such others for file operations and just tested ans saw that `File('filename')` does the magic. learned new thing, well -))

Comment: File is a built in function, which reads text file into array of string.